# TCP Server - new process for each client?

Tags: c, networking, tcp, process

Warning: I'm quite new to C and memory mgmt and all that stuff (coming from interpreted/JITed languages).

So I'm making  a little library for creating TCP servers easily (as an exercise in network programming). An example of usage could look like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "ohsimpletcp.h"

void echo(int socket_fd) {
  char *message = malloc(100 * sizeof(char));

  while (ost_receive(socket_fd, message, 100) > 0) {
    ost_send(socket_fd, message);
  }
}

int main() {
  if (ost_serve(1337, echo) == -1) {
    perror("An error occurred");

    return 1;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

But my question is, for making this thing smoothly concurrent for a high number of clients, do I need to create a new process for every connected client in the backend? Or could I solve this with `select()` somehow?

ohsimpletcp.h:

```
#ifndef REG4IN_OST_H
#define REG4IN_OST_H 1

#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

int ost_serve(int port, void (*handler)(int socket_fd));
int ost_send(int socket_fd, char *message);
int ost_receive(int socket_fd, char *message, int length);

#endif
```

Comment: Processes, threads, polling, they are all valid methods of handling multiple simultaneous connections. Which one to pick depends on the purpose of the server program, and your use-cases. Are the different connections supposed to communicate with each other? Then using separate processes will make it harder, and polling will be easiest. If the connections are completely separated from each other, then processes might be a good solution.

Comment: Also something to think about is the number of simultaneous connections you expect, starting hundreds of processes or threads will bog down the system, as the operating system won't do much else besides switching between the processes or threads. The `select` call is limited to around 1000 connections. And there may be other limitations too. You can however combine these methods, like multiple processes (or threads) which each handle multiple connections though polling.

Comment: Thanks a lot! As this is just a little exercise, I didn't think about any actual use case yet ... but yes it would be great to have the client connection be able to communicate.

Comment: I'll dig into this deeper, thanks for your help.

Comment: Then you probably won't have many simultaneous connections, but if you need it then `select` or `poll` won't be able to handle it. There are other ways to handle several thousands connections though, for example on Linux you could use [`epoll`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/epoll.7.html).

Comment: fork, select, poll are kind of obsolete and architecturally problematic. Newer systems use something like epoll or kqueue. Use an abstraction library such as boost asio.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg : I think that your comments are the answer expected by OP, with the different solutions and their limits. Why did not you make them an answer ?

Comment: @usr disagree. epoll and kqueue are great for things that need them, but are complex to set up and do right. They are in some cases also overkill. A simple fork() plus blocking I/O is easy and Just Works(tm).

Comment: @WouterVerhelst yeah, you really need an abstraction library on top of them but then it's quite nice. fork is problematic if you want to share data between clients. It also strikes me as extremely dirty to clone entire processes. Who knows what's in them?! Libraries might have been loaded, created threads and so on. It's really obsolete.

Comment: @usr fork() is not obsolete. That's like saying PGP is obsolete because there's the CA cartel. Both have their merits and downsides. And no, you really don't need an abstraction layer for a simple fork() call -- it hardly gets any simpler than that.